# Microsoft Asp.net Identity security

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am developing a WebApp based on ASP.net MVC with Login authentication. I got asp.net identity for authentication: standard controllers (from template) such as `Login` with `SignInManager` and so on. Is it safe? Is it easy to hack?

How is its security level? I need to do more than standard "Microsoft" template or I can find anything better?

This is the standard which I refer to :
https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity